# How the display bug of TextView drawableStart can be explained?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, textview

**Update:** Simpler code created and presented here, full layout XML definitions.

When trying to replace the row layout with the icon on the left by the new `drawableStart` attribute of the `TextView` element in XML layout, I can observe the following wrongly displayed last item (captured on Nexus 7):
[image: Notice only the half of the item 3.]

The related code is -- MainActivity:

```
package cz.skil.android.tut.testtextviewdrawablestart;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_list);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
        String[] values = new String[] {"item 1", "item 2", "item 3"};

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, values);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);         
    }
}
```

MyAdapter

```
package cz.skil.android.tut.testtextviewdrawablestart;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.row, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.mylabel);
        textView.setText(values[position]);
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

The `main_list.xml` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" > <!-- Update: here is the bug -->
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and finally the `row.xml` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/mylabel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"

    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/reminder"       

    android:lines="1"
    android:textSize="24sp" >

</TextView>
```

I guess the reason is that the height of the area for displaying the items is calculated from dimensions declared for the text; however, the icon possibly forces a bigger height for the list item.

Can you confirm the behaviour? If yes, why it behaves so? I am new to Android. It is likely I am doing it wrongly.

(The question is loosely related to this one: [Android layout: on TextView and android:drawableStart -- setting size of the icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15340146/1346705)).

Comment: Seems more like a problem in the rest of your layout (the listview? it is in) or your java code if you're adding/adjusted it in there. Try posting some more xml and code.

Comment: The code is from Lars Vogel tutorial. The original layout is here http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#todo_layout (the `todo_row.xml` and `todo_list.xml`), the activity that displayed the screen is the `TodosOverviewActivity.java` shown a bit below (http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#todo_activities). I do not have simpler code, yet. But I will try to prepare it.

Comment: Hmm strange, sorry wouldn't know.

Comment: It's always wrong to set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for a `ListView`. It works as expected with `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`.

Comment: @vmironov: Please write your comment as the answer. I will mark it as accepted. I did not noticed my error. The `match_parent` makes it working. Thanks!

Comment: @vmironov: Please, copy your comment as the answer. I would like to accept it. Have a nice time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always wrong to set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for a ListView. It works as expected with `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`. More detailed explanation could be found here [The World of ListView](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&feature=player_detailpage&t=2445)

Comment: Thanks for the link. This exactly explains the behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Though I don't know if this is intended behaviour or bug, this happens when you use drawableStart. Change it to drawableLeft and it will draw the layout properly.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/mylabel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"

    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/reminder"       

    android:lines="1"
    android:textSize="24sp" >

</TextView>
```

Comment: My +1 so far. I tried also `drawableRight`, `drawableTop`, `drawableBottom`, and they also work a kind of nicely. However, the `drawableEnd` is similarly *wrong* as `drawableStart`. Then what is the purpose of `drawableStart` and `drawableEnd`?

Comment: It is used for rtl-language support. Ideally it should behave the same as drawableLeft for English(unless there is another purpose for it). Have a look at here http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html#42-native-rtl

Comment: Thanks. The RTL reason makes sense in the context. If anyone capable to say whether it is a bug or not?